# Mono Swagger API spec vs multi, for microservices

Tags: swagger, microservices, openapi, openapi-generator, swagger-codegen

In microservices, where there are 30 services for example, creating API spec in swagger (oas) for each can be problematic since there will be many generated codes. In addition, when Domain (common api inswagger) changes, we should go and update all of the apis who refrencing it to the new version. It can be tedious. However, doing a monorepo, will force version increasing of the whole services, even if a change was occurred on one of them.

I am a bit confused about this. What approach should I adopt?

In Github, we do monorepo. What do you prefer in swagger?